# Moving the ADSL modem: Best way of extending the cabling

Tags: networking, ethernet, adsl, phone, cabling

I have had my phone company bring a direct cable from their FTTN switches in the basement to my living room. The cable they have used is a typical Cat5e. The company's modem has a RJ11 connector though, so the cable is terminated by some sort of RJ45 to RJ11 keystone jack / wall socket (see below).

I have recently redecorated my living room and I have to move the modem to the other side of the room. This requires about 10m/35ft of additional cabling. Given that *recabling is not an option*, I see two solutions for this:

- **Simple way:** Use a 10m long phone cable (like this) to carry the signal to the other side of the room.
- **Sophisticated way:** Replace the company's wall socket with a Cat5e inline coupler (like this), carry the signal across the room using Cat5e cable and reinstall the company's wall socket right where the modem is located now.

I wonder if there is any merit in the second solution that makes it worth the effort. I just don't want to sacrifice too much signal quality and I am not sure whether these two solutions will significantly affect that over this short distance: One solution uses less connectors, and the other relies on a potentially less noise-prone cable (cat5e vs phone cable).

Oh, and probably there are other solutions I haven't thought about... So, don't hesitate to make suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RJ11 can't be Cat5e - Cat5e requires all 8 pins of an RJ45.  Most likely what they're supplying is a vDSL line from their equipment to he modem but the specifics can vary wildly.

The 'least loss' method is to leave the modem next to the wall socket (most modems can be wall mounted) and run Cat5 between the modem and your router.  But the simple method you've suggested may not cause you enough loss to be a problem.

Comment: I would have left it there if it wasn't a humongous beast. I agree that the line is probably a vDSL. They just use a Cat5e to carry the signal.